# How exactly does CDialog::Create() work in MFC? Does some of its calls require the use of a mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, mutex

```
myDlg = new Dlg(doc, myDlg , myDlgID);
myDlg -> Create(myDlgID, this);
myDlg -> ChangeFolder(directory);
```

In the `ChangeFolder` function I use things, which are normally created only in OnInitDialog()

Is it necessary to use a mutex in the constructor and in the `OnInitDialog()` function to ensure that the ChangeFolder function will not be called before `OnInitDialog()`?

From what I have read, the MFC library, of which the `CDialog::Create` function is a part, is a tool for communicating with the Windows API.

The Create function creates a window by sending appropriate messages to Windows. Windows responds and the ::OnInitDialog function is called.

Since I cannot predict in advance when Windows will respond, I have to use a mutex that will be unlocked at the end of this function.

Is the above a correct way of thinking?

Comment: Why not just swap the order of the calls to `Create` and `ChangeFolder` ?  Or even remove the call to `ChangeFolder` and pass the `directory` as a parameter to the `Dlg` constructor?

Comment: *"Is the above a correct way of thinking?"* - No. GUI code is (on *every* platform) strictly single-threaded. You do not need a mutex of any kind to establish this, and if you were to use a (non-recursive) mutex, you'd end up with a deadlock. The real challenge here is understanding the order in which functions are being called. MFC doesn't help discover this.

Answer (score 3):

The `Dlg()` constructor is not documented (and taking as a parameter the dialog it is going to create... seems wrong too).

You need to read more of MFC (and maybe Win32 too) documentation. Your considerations about threading are not valid (rather assumptions and worries), as everything will work fine: `Create()` will create the Win32 modeless dialog<sup>(1)</sup> and call `OnInitDialog()` just before the dialog is about to be displayed. To make sure that `ChangeFolder()` will be called after `OnInitDialog()`, just call it inside `OnInitDialog()`. In addition, not only these functions are blocking (returning after they fully complete - the caller "waits" them), they also (typically) all run in the context of the main (UI) thread, ie there are no two or more threads to need synchronized access, so objects like the mutex make no sense. The application will "yield", ie start processing messages again, after the (blocking) `Create()`-`OnInitDialog()`-`ChangeFolder()` calls are finished.

**(1)** Do you really want to create a modeless dialog? Your code is not correct then, you need to call the constructor with no arguments and then call `Create()`, as demonstrated in the example in the `CDialog::Create()` documentation.

Comment: Dlg is a class I created that inherits from CDialog. In fact, I should maybe point that out

Comment: "To make sure that ChangeFolder() will be called after OnInitDialog(), just call it inside OnInitDialog()."

Let's assume I can't do this because it is also used in other places. Then what?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
You know, since MCF is some kind of API that talks to Windows, I thought there might be some multithreading involved.
Then I won't use mutexes.
Thanks again!

Comment: Where else may `ChangeFolder()` called from? You define it as a member of the `Dlg` class. Should it be that way (ie one "Folder" per `Dlg` instance) or instead defined for the whole app? It should be global or static or a free function then ("singleton"). And you can use control variables (flags) eg allowing the call or containing info like whether the call has taken place. These should be defined the same level as `ChangeFolder()`, ie global/static if `ChangeFolder()` is global, or class members if `ChangeFolder()` is class member too. No need for sync objects, if only one thread is involved

Comment: @MieszkoPasierbek If you make the folder parm optional and add it as a member parm.  Within OnInit, test member to see If it's empty.  If so, don't call ChangeFolder, if it is non-empty, call it.  Client now has control over when to call ChangeFolder by providing that parameter (or not) in the ctor.  Ctors define the initial state of the object.  However, with MFC windows, creation is a 2-step process, but the ctor can still be utilized the "normal" way.  You can overload the ctor, or provide a long list of "optional" initial state parms in the lone ctor - whatever works best for the clients.